# Spring batch - need to use an object in itemProcessor/itemWriter but not persist it

Tags: spring-batch

I need to access an object in both `itemProcessor` and `itemWriter` but I don't want to persist it in the `executionContext`. I would read this object in a pre-processing step.
What is the best way to do that?

So far what I have is - I put the object in the `jobExecutionContext`, then I set the scope of my `itemProcessor` to "step" and bind a property of the `itemProcessor` to `"#{stepExecution.jobExecution.executionContext}"`. This does give me access to my object. But I am stuck at two issues with this solution:

1. When do I remove the object from the context so that it doesn't stay persisted, it has to be after all the items are done.
2. My object could be huge and it seems the column for the context is of size 2500.

Is this a good solution and if it is, how do I solve the two concerns mentioned above. And if not, is there a good way to do this in spring batch or is caching the best way to go?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to update what I ended up doing - I created a cache object and used job execution id as the cache key.

Answer (score -2):

execution/job/step ... Context uses by Spring batch are meant to be persisted in the metadata of spring batch for the restartable feature to name one!

What i have done previously is creating a normal spring bean with the object yo need and simply @autowired it in your Processor and writer!

Job Done.